# mutate many columns in dplyr for log(1+x)

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to do something like:

```
mutate_each(myDF, funs(log(1+x)), myvar1:myvar10
```

Basically, for every column in myDF between myvar1 to myvar10, I want to take log(1 +x). However, I'm not sure how to write that into `funs`. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `log(1 + .)` inside `funs`, like so:

```
mutate_each(myDF, funs(log(1 + .)), myvar1:myvar10)
```

For example:

```
mutate_each(mtcars, funs(log(1 + .)), mpg:wt)
```

Comment: but what if I already had a period. my exact code is being piped-in via: mutate_each(., funs(log(1+x)), myvar1:myvar10). There would then be 2 periods?

Comment: @user1357015 Yes, that will still work. However, you don't need that first period to pipe in the first argument. You could just do `myDF %>% mutate_each(funs(log(1 + .)), myvar1:myvar10)`

Comment: Cool thanks. I like to keep the period to see where the pip goes. I know I don't need it. Is there a good tutorial that I can see how R treats the period. Is it just lexical scoping or some such?

Comment: The period is handled within the [magrittr](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) package, particularly the `%>%` function. Running `get("%>%")` will show you the code, which is a bit complicated. [This tutorial](http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/) might help as well.

Comment: Or you could use `log1p()` ;)